# Rendering HTML Form inside Bootstap's popover

Tags: website-design, interface-design

One of my teammate came up with a web design layout of rendering an HTML form inside a **popover**. I've experienced using HTML forms inside a **popup** and it can be made responsive as well. I had an impression that popovers reresents secondary information (like showing additional info). But using forms on a popover? I'm confused. Whats the best practice? What about its responsiveness?

Answer (score 2):

I can see it being used successfully for forms that are outside the flow of the page content, for example, a login form. But you should test in your specific case to see if it's clear that the form is there and what it does and if it's usable in its own context.

If you're using bootstrap, responsiveness should not be an issue, form elements should adapt to container width.